# Switch scope between the browser and dev tools (normal pane and mini console) with keyboard

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome, when using the dev tools, I sometimes want to switch between the actual bowser window, and the dev tools window.   What keyboard shortcut exists if at all? Currently I have to click on on window to switch scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all DT shortcuts written down in the `Settings -> Shortucts` menu (open DT settings by clicking on the 'cog' icon) and in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/shortcuts). Unfortunately, there is no shortcut for switching between Chrome and DT.

However, if you have Chrome and DevTools in separate windows you should be able to switch between them using 'cycle between open windows' feature (available on most OSes):

- [Windows](http://www.pcworld.com/article/238080/Windows.html)
- [OSX](https://superuser.com/questions/45310/switch-between-windows-on-mac-os-x)
- [Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50146/is-there-a-command-equivalent-cycle-through-windows)